# Recently purchased domain name at SiteGround redirects to a GoDaddy parked page

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, godaddy, name

I'm doing a freelance job and the client provided me with the account details of a recently purchased SiteGround account, I proceeded to put a test index.php in the public_html folder. But when I try to access the website through the domain name ([goldenbranch-dates.com](http://goldenbranch-dates.com)) it redirects me to a GoDaddy page that says :

> Welcome to goldenbranch-dates.com.
>   This Web page is parked for FREE, courtesy of GoDaddy.com.

Yet I can still access the index.php through the [IP address](http://146.66.92.114/~golde747).

Is this a DNS propagation issue that will be auto resolved in time or something more ?

Comment: Have you set up the DNS at all, ever?

Comment: Nope, I'm completely new to this. But I made other projects before and didn't exactly need to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain is indeed registered at GoDaddy:

```
> Domain Name: goldenbranch-dates.com Registry Domain ID:
> 2353931542_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.godaddy.com
> Registrar URL: http://www.godaddy.com Updated Date:
> 2019-01-20T15:30:09Z Creation Date: 2019-01-20T15:30:08Z Registrar
> Registration Expiration Date: 2020-01-20T15:30:08Z Registrar:
> GoDaddy.com, LLC
```

The domain resolves to a GoDaddy IP address:

```
dig goldenbranch-dates.com +short    
50.63.202.37

whois 50.63.202.37
{snip}
NetRange:       50.62.0.0 - 50.63.255.255
CIDR:           50.62.0.0/15
NetName:        GO-DADDY-COM-LLC
NetHandle:      NET-50-62-0-0-1
Parent:         NET50 (NET-50-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:       AS26496
Organization:   GoDaddy.com, LLC (GODAD)
```

So it looks like you'll need to setup DNS to point to SiteGround. They provide instructions at https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/getting-started/initial-domain-setup/. Essentially, you need to follow their instructions, or, if you don't want to use their DNS servers, then login to the GoDaddy control panel, and setup an "A" record to point the @ (root of the domain) to `146.66.92.114`.